# Calling php from javascript and return a value from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I send a variable from js to php and in php i am running a query using the variable i got from js. After running the query i need to return the output of the query to js. I succeeded in sendind the variable and running the query.But unable to return the output.How can i return it?

Here is the code

JS

```
function abc () {
    var url = 'server/set_data.php';
    var paramstring = "vr=ViewLog&val=" + activityID1;
    ctype = "TEXT";
    AJAXRequest(url, paramstring, ctype, "VerifyData");
}
```

PHP

```
if(trim($_REQUEST[vr]) == 'ViewLog')
{
    if (trim($_REQUEST[val]) != "")
    {
        $sql="select abc from table where id='".$_REQUEST[val]."'";
        echo $sql;    
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your JS function. You're missing the `()`. It should be `function abc () {`.

Comment: Tip for your questions: Define all functions you use or tell us (via tags) which framework you are using: How is `AJAXRequest` defined? If I knew how it works, I might tell what is wrong. ;) You are always welcome to update your original post in order to correct errors or to complete the information! (Also applies to the code you posted into the comment to my answer.

Comment: Your echo in inside your php file should be the response. From your code it seems that you're using 'TEXT' return type. That means, that all output from your PHP script will be received in your ajax callback routine (I guess it is 'VerifyData') as plain text. Please tell, which library are you using for Ajax and I'll tell you in details how to catch the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jQuery code, it will work

```
$.ajax({
    type   :"POST",
    data   :"vr=ViewLog&val="+activityID1,
    url    :'server/set_data.php', 
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg); // here you can get the result from php page
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that the two conditional statements are executed the right way?
I would set the array index in quotes:

```
if(trim($_REQUEST["vr"]) == 'ViewLog')
{
  if (trim($_REQUEST["val"]) != "")
  {
    $sql="select abc from table where id='".$_REQUEST[val]."'";
    echo $sql;   
  }
}
```

Additionally: You only return the SQL request string and not the result of a SQL request. Is this intended?

Comment: now i changed the php script as follows
        if(trim($_REQUEST[vr]) == 'ViewLog')
        {
  if (trim($_REQUEST[val]) != "")
 {
  $sql=mysql_query("select abc from table where     id='".$_REQUEST[val]."'");
       ;
   echo $sql;
  
   
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ))
  {
   $log=$info['abc'];
  }
  mysql_free_result($sql);
  echo $log;   
 }
}

and i get response from php. but unable to get it into js.